# Getting started with React in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webstorm

I am very new to React and IDEs for frontend development.

I am trying to use React in WebStorm. I made a new project with "React starter kit" in WebStorm. Now a whole bunch of packages got created under my project. Where should I start writing my react code?

Also I have read that I need to add library "node.js v1.8.1 core modules" and "Node.js Globals" but I'm not able to find them. I am attaching snippets for better understanding.

[image: Project Explorer. Where Should I write my code]

[image: Libraries showing]

Comment: "node.js  core modules" and "Node.js Globals" libraries have been merged in a single Node.js Core library that can be enabled in Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM.

Comment: to start writing your own code, edit files in project src dir. But, as @Kaleb Portillo mentioned, starter-kit is not the best choice to start with React if you are new to this framework

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with react-native you better not start with a "starter-kit".

I recommend you start form the very beginning, with the simple tutorial in the react-native docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

After you get some familiarity with it, you will be able to use a stater-kit more properly.

As for the project in your WebStorm, you need to look for the files under the `src` directory to edit the react code.

Good luck